# Selecting another site for off-topic questions - a bug?

Tags: support

If a question belongs to another site, and I am voting to close it, how can I choose the right one? When selecting "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" I can only see UX.SE meta site.

Comment: There are 5 slots reserved for site migrations - at the moment, only one is filled for this site and goes to meta UX. In order for others to be filled, this site needs to show that the suggested slots (you suggest them here on this meta) will go to sites where this site migrates to often and that the migrations are usually accepted. I don't think the [migration stats](http://ux.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats) show support for much (but, I could be wrong).

Comment: Until other sites are listed in the migration option, and even afterwords, when you think a question should be migrated to another site, flag it for moderator attention and in the text box that appears say it should be migrated to another site, and state which one, i.e. "This questions should be migrated to Stack Overflow."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a bug since it's a moderator only option to migrate the question away to another site. Often we communicate with the receiving site mods to know if they want it, think it suits their site objective and is as well written as it's supposed to be.

Your job could be to suggest move to another site using the comment on close vote.

Comment: Well, that is clear, yet I still have an option to click either "Close" or "Flag", then select "Off topic" and suggest migration. Just at the last stage (Flagging>Closing>Off-Topic>Migration) I can only select UX.SE Meta. I think people should either be able to point the suggested site or not see this option at all (and be informed that they only can leave a comment to move it somewhere else).

Comment: @DominikOslizlo That must be suggested on the [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) site, since it's a stackexchange wide change